# Camel cannot find {{xxx}} in properties from text after update to camel 3.0.0-RC3 using spring boot 2.2.4

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, apache-camel-3

I was using spring boot `2.2.4.RELEASE` and camel version `2.23.0`

In order to make camel have access to properties and use them in uri routes using `{{ }}`

adding `camel-spring-boot-starter` dependency and defining `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, `SpringCamelContext` bean was enough to make it work

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = false, value= {"classpath:myProperties.properties"})
public class MyApp {

    ...
    @Bean
    public SpringCamelContext camelContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        return new SpringCamelContext(applicationContext);
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

--

Now, after I updated `camel-spring-boot-starter` to `3.0.0-RC3` following the migration guide and after fixing the imports for the components. On runtime, camel cannot find properties and I get this:

`Property with key [xxx] not found in properties from text: activemq:queue:{{xxx}}`

Any Ideas what changed and why `{{ }}` is not working anymore in my routes?

---

**UPDATE 1**

I updated spring boot to `2.2.6.RELEASE` and `camel-spring-boot-starter` to `3.2.0` from `org.apache.camel.springboot` I am still getting the same thing...

Routes are not fancy.

I need for `{{ }}` to read `xxx` value from `myProperties.properties`

Using `@Value("${xxx}")` works, spring can access it, and I could pass it to the route URI String.

Accessing `{{xxx}}` in camel URIs is what stopped working after the update.

```
@Component
public class MyRoutes extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("activemq:queue:{{xxx}}")
            .to("activemq:topic:targetTopic");
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I mirrored the test made by accepted answer. Removing `SpringCamelContext` and `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` beans did the trick.

I removed the bean `SpringCamelContext` and it worked. Apparently this new spring camel starter takes care of `SpringCamelContext` by itself and my bean overrode the auto configuration related to camel reading properties using `{{ }}`

I also removed the bean `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and @Value did not stop working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the application.properties file in your spring boot application? If so {{}} should work. It would help to see your camel code though.

**Edit 1:**

This works for me. I am running Camel 3.2.0 with Spring Boot 2.2.6. I have a single property `prop=Hello World` in a file `myProperties.properties` in my classpath. I did not have to define the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and `SpringCamelContext` beans

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = false, value = {"classpath:myProperties.properties"})
public class DemoApplication extends RouteBuilder{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer:foo?repeatCount=1")
        .log("{{prop}}");
    }
}
```

**Log**

```
2020-04-28 21:26:57.904  INFO 10392 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Route: route6 started and consuming from: timer://foo
2020-04-28 21:26:57.921  INFO 10392 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
2020-04-28 21:26:57.937  INFO 10392 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.2.0 (CamelContext: camel-6) started in 0.067 seconds
2020-04-28 21:26:57.938  INFO 10392 --- [  restartedMain] c.p.testproperties.DemoApplication       : Started DemoApplication in 0.406 seconds (JVM running for 82.808)
2020-04-28 21:26:57.955  INFO 10392 --- [  restartedMain] .ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener : Condition evaluation unchanged
2020-04-28 21:26:58.920  INFO 10392 --- [4 - timer://foo] route6                                   : Hello World
```

**Edit 2:**

You may be fetching your property from the Exchange, which may cause this issue. Fetching properties from the exchange has been changed since Camel version 3.0.0. Can you try `exchangeProperty("xxx")`

Comment: I updated my question. There is nothing special or relevant in application.properties. there is nothing special about the routes as well. routes having `{{xxx}}` used to work before the update.

Comment: Added a test in the edits. It is working fine for me!

Comment: I removed the two beans `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and `SpringCamelContext` and it worked. I think it has something to do with camel 3 allowing one only camel context to run so the starter package did the job and my `SpringCamelContext` overrode it along with the auto config related to properties. Marking as accepted answer. Thanks.