# Why property doesn't get evaluated correctly in Camel 3.7.3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, migration, apache-camel-3

I have a route

```
String XYZ = "xyz";

from(URL_A)
  .bean(PropertiesSetterBean.class)
  .to("${property." + XYZ + "}")
```

where `PropertiesSetterBean` is:

```
@Component
class PropertiesSetterBean {
  public void copyProperties(@Headers Map<String, Object> headers, @ExchangeProperties Map<String, Object> properties) {
    properties.put("xyz", "direct:test")
  }
}
```

The error I get:

> Failed to create route route1 at: >>>
> DynamicTo[${property.xyz}] <<< in
> route: Route(route1)[From[seda:inEvents?concurrentCon...
> because of Property with key
> [property.xyz] not found in properties
> from text: ${property.xyz}

It looks like `bean` doesn't get executed.

I use camel:3.7.3, spring-boot:2.4.3, java:11

Steps I did:

- I read the migration guide
- Looked at available code snippets on GitHub
- Search StackOverflow
- Talked to colleagues

I looked into a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61477348/camel-cannot-find-xxx-in-properties-from-text-after-update-to-camel-3-0-0-rc).

And still, I cannot triage the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

I added the processor:

```
.process(exchange -> {
  System.out.println("This is my property: " + exchange.getProperty("xyz"));
})
```

It works. In the meantime, I still cannot retrieve this property with `simple` DSL in Camel.

Comment: Shouldn't `properties.put("xyz", "direct:test")` be `properties.put("property.xyz", "direct:test")`?

Comment: @Lino, I don't know how it should look like be in Camel 3.7.3, but the syntax that I posted is valid in Camel 2.X.X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of search with no result, I bumped into an [old post](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/how-to-check-a-property-inside-of-a-exchange-property-td5817857.html).

To access the property, I will need to use `"${exchangeProperty." + XYZ + "}"`.

**Note:**

- It worked with Camel 2.X.X, so beware of this change.
- If you have a collision between Spring and Camel placeholders, use `$simple` instead of `$`.
- In Camel 3.X.X you will need to check where your properties located and repoint them to `exchangeProperty`